# How could I transfer each cell to different form then separate them to 2 cells ? CSV python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a number.csv file and each cell contain one digit. For example, it looks like this..

```
    0,1,2 
   -1,0,1
    1,2,-1
```

Then I'd like to transform each digit to a certain name according to my rule.

```
   # The rule is: 
   # 0 for AA
   # 1 for AB
   # 2 for BB
   # -1 for 00 (that's double zero)
```

Therefore I will get something like...

```
   AA,AB,BB
   00,AA,AB
   AB,BB,00
```

Then I have to divide each cell to two cells, and write into a new result.csv file. Finally it would look like....

```
   A,A,A,B,B,B
   0,0,A,A,A,B
   A,B,B,B,0,0
```

I only know how to replace each digit to a certain name (eg. 0 to AA), then I stuck at how to divide AA to A,A for each cell and separate each row to next line.

Does anyone know how to work out this problem by csv module or even a smarter way to achieve this?

Much appreciated,

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Yeah I already tried this but I stuck how to divide each cell and separate each row to different next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(r'G:\number.csv', 'r') as f:  # read
    content = f.read()
    with open(r'G:\number-post.csv', 'wb') as fh: # write
        fh.write(content.replace('-1','O,O').replace('0','A,A').replace('1','A,B').replace('2','B,B').replace('O','0'))
```

Just replace the file name above to your corresponding filename.

Comment: Thanks, but when I write them to .csv file then open file it doesn't separate to next cell automatically.

Comment: I had changed my answer.

Comment: I changed my answer again. Just use `open` to open that file.

Comment: Thanks, will get a try!

Answer (score 1):

Using **VBA**

```
Sub user3058889()
    Dim d1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "C:\TestFolder\input.csv"
    s2 = "C:\TestFolder\output.csv"
    Close #1
    Close #2
    Open s1 For Input As #1
    Open s2 For Output As #2
    Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            textline = Replace(textline, "-1", "z")
            textline = Replace(textline, "0", "A,A")
            textline = Replace(textline, "1", "A,B")
            textline = Replace(textline, "2", "B,B")
            textline = Replace(textline, "z", "0,0")

            Print #2, textline
    Loop

    Close #1
    Close #2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I have no ideas about how to work with VBA, still appreciated with your answer. :)